# Unable to get query string params in struts 2 action class

Tags: java, struts2

Here is my action class:

```
public class ForgotPassword extends ActionSupport{

    private String j_username;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("FORGOT PASSWORD ACTION CALLED");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return j_username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String j_username) {
        System.out.println("Username received is " + j_username);
        this.j_username = j_username;
    }   
}
```

I have declared default interceptors in struts.xml which includes:

```
<interceptor-ref name="params">
    <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

From html page I am sending params to action class like this:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username"/>

    <div style="margin-top:20px"> 
        <a class="forgot_password" 
           onclick="forgotPassword()" id="resetAnchor">Forgot Password</a>    
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function forgotPassword() {
            var ctx = '${pageContext.request.contextPath}';
            var username = document.getElementById('j_username').value;
            if (username !== null && username !== "") {
                var username = document.getElementById('j_username').value;
                console.log('username is ', username);
                document.getElementById('resetAnchor').href = ctx + "/forgotPassword?j_username=" + username;
            } else {
                alert('please provider username');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Everything looks fine but I am unable to print this line inside setter method:

```
System.out.println("Username received is " + j_username);
```

It prints only this line: `System.out.println("FORGOT PASSWORD ACTION CALLED");`

Here is the action defined in struts.xml:

```
<action name="forgotPassword" class="com.actions.ForgotPassword">
     <interceptor-ref name="params"/>  
    <result name="success">/reset.jsp</result>
</action>
```

what I'm I missing?

Comment: did you mentioned the action name that is `/forgotPassword` in the struts.xml file.

Comment: @Poornima The page redirects so that mean its returning `Success`

Comment: change the variable name as username in html page and in action class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getJ_username() {
    return j_username;
}
public void setJ_username(String j_username) {
    System.out.println("Username received is " + j_username);
    this.j_username = j_username;
}
```

Just change your `setter` and `getter` method. because it reads the method. not the variable name.

Comment: No problem sir. if my answer is right. you can kindly check it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the setter/getter methods.

Could you try this.

```
 public String getJ_username() {

        return j_username;
    }

    public void setJ_username( String j_username ) {

        this.j_username = j_username;
    }
```

To avoid such mistakes I suggest to use IDE help rather creating setter/getter methods on your own.

If you are using **Eclipse** you can follow below steps.

1. **RightCLick on the variable** you want to generate setter/getter methods.
2. **Source ==> Generate Getters and Setters...**
3. Check Seter and Getter check boxes click `OK`.

**Step1**
[image: Step1]

**Step2**

[image: Step2]